# Regular Expression to Allow Only Numbers

Tags: validation, jquery-validate

i want to give validation condition like,

```
         var BlkAccountIdV = $('#txtBlkAccountId').val();
     if (BlkAccountIdV == "") {            
        document.getElementById('lblAccountId').innerText = "Enter Valid AccountID";
        errorflag=1;
    }
```

if condition should be Executed only when entered text box value contains Letter.What value can i give inside Quotation marks(if (BlkAccountIdV == "") )?

Answer (score 2):

```
var re = /[^0-9]/g;
var error = re.test(BlkAccountIdV);
```

`error` will be true if value of `BlkAccountIdV` is not numeric

I.e, this regex will match everything except numbers

So your code should look somehow like this:

```
var BlkAccountIdV = $('#txtBlkAccountId').val();
var re = /[^0-9]/g;    
if ( re.test(BlkAccountIdV) ){  
    // found a non-numeric value, handling error
    document.getElementById('lblAccountId').innerText = "Enter Valid AccountID";
    errorflag=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (BlkAccountIdV.match(/[0-9]+/) == null )`

Answer (score 0):

In if condition you can use isNaN() function. This checks whether string is 'not a number'

So in your case if this condition not valid, Then string is number

```
if(!isNaN(BlkAccountIdV) && BlkAccountIdV != ''){
  //Your code
}
```